# Can 'this' pointer be different than the object's pointer?

Tags: c++

I've recently came across this strange function in some class:

```
void* getThis() {return this;}
```

And later in the code it is sometimes used like so: `bla->getThis()` (Where *bla* is a pointer to an object of the class where this function is defined.)
And I can't seem to realize what this can be good for. Is there any situation where a pointer to an object would be different than the object's `this` (where `bla != bla->getThis()`)?

It seems like a stupid question but I wonder if I'm missing something here..

Comment: Are there templates involved?  Or inheritance?  Is the return type the same type as the class containing the function?  Because otherwise there's no point at all

Comment: In what context is `getThis` called?

Comment: looks like it's for casting to `void*`. Why they didn't just cast to `void*` I have no idea. You see some funny things in other people's code.

Comment: Yeah, casting in general is the only thing I could think of.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, always in other people's code, never in ours (of course). ;)

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yes. There are both templates and Inheritance involved. How does each affect the situation?

Comment: @syam I just never open up code files older than a month. My code is rock solid.

Comment: @JustSid Ah, glad to see there are some competent developers left out there! :p

Comment: @MooingDuck since it returns `void*`, I can't see how even templates or inheritance would make a difference. Effectively, the function is returning the implicit `this` parameter directly, and casting it to `void` regardless of the method's type. That's as close to a no-op as I could imagine.

Comment: @Dave If multiple inheritance is involved this may perhaps make sense in very specific scenarios. Otherwise, I'm as much at loss as you.

Comment: @Dave - there are no casts in this code. It **converts** to `void*`. That doesn't need a cast.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course, the pointer values can be different! Below an example which demonstrates the issue (you may need to use `derived1` on your system instead of `derived2` to get a difference). The point is that the `this` pointer typically gets adjusted when virtual, multiple inheritance is involved. This may be a rare case but it happens.

One potential use case of this idiom is to be able to restore objects of a known type after storing them as `void const*` (or `void*`; the `const` correctness doesn't matter here): if you have a complex inheritance hierarchy, you can't just cast any odd pointer to a `void*` and hope to be able to restore it to its original type! That is, to easily obtain, e.g., a pointer to `base` (from the example below) and convert it to `void*`, you'd call `p->getThis()` which is a lot easier to `static_cast<base*>(p)` and get a `void*` which can be safely cast to a `base*` using a `static_cast<base*>(v)`: you can reverse the implicit conversion but only if you cast back to the exact type where the original pointer came from. That is, `static_cast<base*>(static_cast<void*>(d))` where `d` is a pointer to an object of a type derived from `base` is illegal but `static_cast<base*>(d->getThis())` is legal.

Now, why is the address changing in the first place? In the example `base` is a virtual base class of two derived classes but there could be more. All subobjects whose class virtually inherits from `base` will share one common `base` subject in object of a further derived class (`concrete` in the example below). The location of this `base` subobject may be different relative to the respective derived subobject depending on how the different classes are ordered. As a result, the pointer to the `base` object is generally different from the pointers to the subobjects of classes virtually inheriting from `base`. The relevant offset will be computed at compile-time, when possible, or come from something like a vtable at run-time. The offsets are adjusted when converting pointers along the inheritance hierarchy.

```
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
    void const* getThis() const { return this; }
};

struct derived1
    : virtual base
{
    int a;
};

struct derived2
    : virtual base
{
    int b;
};

struct concrete
    : derived1
    , derived2
{
};

int main()
{
    concrete c;
    derived2* d2 = &c;
    void const* dptr = d2;
    void const* gptr = d2->getThis();
    std::cout << "dptr=" << dptr << " gptr=" << gptr << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Dave: As Steve Clamage correctly pointed out a long time ago, "an obfuscated C++ contest would be like shooting fish in a barrel"! There is a real use of this explicit conversion, though: you can cast the pointer obtained from `getThis()` to a `base const*`. You can't do the same with a pointer obtained from `d2` by converting it to `void const*` (you could cast a pointer thus obtained to a `derived2 const*`, however, i.e., undo the implicit conversion).

Comment: +1 because multiple inheritance is the only scenario I can think of where this could perhaps make sense. Still I can't think of a practical use, but if there is *one* thing I really know it's that I know nothing. :)

Comment: @DietmarKühl oh I can see the purpose. But my point was that in this case it should be named `getBase` or similar, not `getThis`!

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl - wow... could you add to the answer why this is the case? I can see the result but still don't understand why it occurs... Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: Well... Assume the code using `getThis()` happens to be generic, i.e., templatized code: the generic code really likes to use a consistent name like `getThis()` rather than `getWidget()` sometimes and `getGadget()` at other times.

Comment: @Jimbo: I have edited my answer to include a motivation. all: if there are still questions about that let me know and I'll try to address these!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No.</strike> Yes, in limited circumstances.

This looks like it is something inspired by Smalltalk, in which all objects have a `yourself` method. There are probably some situations in which this makes code cleaner. As the comments note, this looks like an odd way to even implement this idiom in c++.

In your specific case, I'd grep for actual usages of the method to see how it is used.

Comment: +1 just for the `grep` part. Honestly, in 20+ years of C++ I have never seen a situation where this construct would be needed, but maybe that's just me...

Comment: @syam I can't think of an instance, but my experience with smalltalk is limited. I assume it became a thing in that language for a reason, which may or may not apply in C++.

Comment: With `void* p0 = bla; void* p1 = bla->getThis();` it is possible that `p0 != p1`! All it requires is that `bla` is a pointer to a suitably constructed type.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Noted. I'm still at a loss to think of an actual use.

Answer (score 1):

Your class can have custom `operator&` (so `&a` may not return `this` of `a`). That's why [std::addressof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) exists.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across something like this many (many many) years ago. If I recall correctly, it was needed when a class is manipulating other instances of the same class. One example might be a container class that can contain its own type/(class?).

Answer (score 0):

That might be a way to override the this keyword.
Lets say that you have a memory pool, full initialized at the start of your program, for instance you know that at any time you can deal with a max of 50 messages, CMessage.
You create a pool at the size of 50 * sizeof(CMessage) (what ever this class might be), and CMessage implements the getThis function.

That way instead of overriding the new keyword you just override the "this", accessing the pool.
It can also mean that the object might be defined on different memory spaces, lets say on a SRAM, in boot mode, and then on a SDRAM.

It might be that the same instance will return different values for getThis through the program in such a situation, on purpose of course, when overriden.