# Why different `this` address in using multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, std, multiple-inheritance

In C++, it is small sample code that using `std::enable_shared_from_this` and inheritance. The `p` in this code, call a member function fb and fa. The `p` is the same object, but called fa and fb take a different `this` address.

Why take a different address?

code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> using S = std::enable_shared_from_this<T>;

struct A: S<A>    { auto fa() const -> void { std::cerr << this << "\n";} };
struct B: S<B>, A { auto fb() const -> void { std::cerr << this << "\n";} };

auto main() -> int
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<B>();

    p -> fa();
    p -> fb();

    std::cerr << p << "\n";
}
```

result: (tested compilers are clang++-3.2, g++-4.8 and em++-1.12 on Linux Mint 16 KDE and clang++-3.4 in wandbox as a online compiling platform.)

```
0x8376a8
0x837698
0x837698
```

wandbox: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rmcCrR0rqLd7tKfV

Comment: This doesn't even compile with libstdc++, deriving twice from a `enable_shared_from_this` specialization leads to an ambiguous call.

Comment: Revert the order of the multiple inheritance and try again. [Surprise!](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/be4OM6mmpLJNl4qr)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can 'this' pointer be different than the object's pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368594/can-this-pointer-be-different-than-the-objects-pointer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `std::enable_shared_from_this`; it's the general scenario of multiple inheritance. Inside a member function of class `X`, the type of `this` is `X*`, i.e. it points to the `X` subobject of the complete object. So when calling `A::fa()` on a `B` object, `this` refers to the `A` subobject of `B`. That can be offset from the object's initial address, based on the compiler's chosen memory layout.

In other words, an object `B` contains both a base class object `A` and a base class object `S<B>`. Since you listed `S<B>` first, the compiler chose to lay out `S<B>` first in `B`'s layout, and `A` after it. So the memory layout looks something like this:

```
+-------+-----+---------------------------+
| S<B>  | A   | B's non-inherited members |
+-------+-----+---------------------------+
```